# Python multiprocessing + Pipe

Tags: python

Читаю справочник д. Бизли:

1. создается отдельный процесс, который закрывает 2 элемент из кортежа, возвращаемый `pipe()`
2. в основном процессе после создания дополнительного процесса закрывается 1 элемент из кортежа.

Получается такая ситуация, что закрыты оба конца канала - как тогда происходит обмен? Я чувствую, что упустил какую-то логическую деталь.
Что я неправильно понял?
Добавлю наверно код:

```
import multiprossing
def adder(pipe):
    server_p, client_p = pipe
    client_p.close()  # закрыли одно направление 
    while True:
        try:
            x,y = server_p.recv()
        except EOFError:
            break
    result = x+y
    server_p.send(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    (server_p, client_p) = multiprocessing.Pipe()
    adder_p = multiprocessing.Process(target=adder, args=((server_p,client_p),))
    adder_p.start()
    server_p.close() # закрыли другое
    # в итоге оба направления закрыты,да?
    #дальше не важно
```

Comment: Один процесс закрывает один конец, оставляя другой, другой -- наоборот. В каждом процессе по одному открытому хэндлу -- нормальная однонаправленная труба...

Comment: В родительском закрыли server_p (client_p открыт), в дочернем -- client_p (server_p открыт). Всё нормально, по одному Connection на процесс открыто.

Насчёт однонаправленности трубы -- поторопился (Pipe() вызвана без параметра, т.е. по умолчанию -- duplex)

Comment: Ну, к сказанному @alexlz добавить нечего :)

Могу только посоветовать вам пока не Бизли (это, все же, справочник, не учебник. Но справочник отличный, да), а книгу Марка Лутца, двухтомник "Программирование на Python". По теме вопроса - том 1, глава 5 ("Системные инструменты параллельного выполнения"). Ну и вообще вся вторая часть в этом томе, судя по объекту изучения, пожалуй, будет вам интересна.

Answer (score 1):

Из комментариeв @alexlz:

Один процесс закрывает один конец, оставляя другой, другой -- наоборот. В каждом процессе по одному открытому хэндлу -- нормальная однонаправленная труба.

В родительском закрыли server_p (client_p открыт), в дочернем -- client_p (server_p открыт). Всё нормально, по одному Connection на процесс открыто. Насчёт однонаправленности трубы -- поторопился (Pipe() вызвана без параметра, т.е. по умолчанию -- duplex)