# Как реализовать программу при помощи multiprocessing.Pipe?

Tags: python-3.x

Как при помощи multiprocessing.Pipe реализовать такую программу?

```
def return_sum(x):
    return x+x
```

Допустим, я этот скрипт упакую в EXE, как мне из другого скрипта взаимодействовать с ним, я отправляю число 2 - EXE-ник возвращает 4?

Comment: ответ никак - тут 2 никак не связанных между собой вопроса, 1) как передать/получить данные в сторонюю exe-программу и 2) как работает multiprocessing.Pipe.

Comment: ) Хорошо на первый вопрос можете ответить ?

Comment: посмотри это http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/189393/python-multiprocessing-pipe и https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes

Comment: Я этот скрипт и хочу раскидать на потребитель поставщик 2 EXE файла один работает в фоне....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если потребитель/поставщик, то можно сделать сокетами. Потребитель работает в фоне, ожидает подключения поставщика, ожидает данных от поставщика, чтото вычисляет и отправляет результат поставщику.

потребитель

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM

def return_sum(x):
    return x+x

with socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) as consumer:
    consumer.bind(('localhost', 18888))
    consumer.listen(1)
    print('ожидание соедениия поставщика')
    provider, ip = consumer.accept()
    print('поставщик подключен', ip)
    while True:
        data = provider.recv(1024)
        consumer_data = data.decode()
        if consumer_data == 'quit':
            provider.close()
            break
        else:
            print('от поставщик получено %s' % consumer_data)
            result = return_sum(int(consumer_data))  # чтото вычислить
            provider.send(str(result).encode())  # отправить результат поставщику
```

поставщик

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM

with socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) as provider:
    provider.connect(('localhost', 18888))
    while True:
        data = input('ввод данных для потребителя: ')
        if data:
            provider.send(str.encode(data))
            result = provider.recv(1024)
            print('результат от потребителя - %s' % result)
        else:
            provider.send(str.encode('quit'))
            break
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за код !, через сокеты у меня есть реализация просто хочю досконально изучить multiproccesing . тема я думаю нормальная .